# Auto rotation or the views

Tags: ios, device-orientation

i am working with the application and want to stop the rotation when i move the device to landscape mode. Please help me out regarding this. Your help will be much appriciable.

Answer (score 1):

just click on your project and click on `General` Tab and go to `Deployment Info` section

and unselect the `Landscape Left` and `Landscape Right` option.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Select the project` and then go to the `General Tab`. There you can see the section `Deployment Info` with the option `Device Orientation`. Unselect all the orientations you don't need.

[image: XCode Setting]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to support landscape orientation, in Xcode, select your project in the Navigator, then go to Deployment info and uncheck Landscape left and right.

Answer (score 0):

In your "Deployment Info" go to  "summary" there are "supprted device orientation" , you can set the device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

As above is one way to set portrait apps ....

but another way throughout coding like u set particular view portrait...

add this method  in your `view controller`.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait ;
}
```

u can also set the multiple value like ..

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

it is useful for the different view set different orientation ..

Best of luck..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project-> TARGET-> General
In Deployment Info select iPhone/iPad.
Checkmark for desired Device Orientations.